# Dynamically Created DropDownList within a List of Panels is not allowing for Event Handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a UI that creates rows that can be dynamically populated.

I am at the point where I can add a Panel to my list that contains a DropDownList and has an associated Remove Button.

The Remove Button has an OnClick event bound that allows me to remove that specific panel.

I am having an issue when trying to bind a SelectedIndexChanged EventHandler to my DropDownList it does not.

I suspect this had something to do with how I am recreating my controls after every Postback.

I am not asking for or expecting a straightforward "Add this or Change this in the code." I really want to have a understand where I am going wrong, sorry for asking so much! :s

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Showing this for the the poster that asked.
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetClustersFromDB(user);
        BindGrid();
        BindState();            
    }
    if (Session["persistControls"] != null)
    {
        persistControls = (List<Panel>)Session["persistControls"];
        int count = 0;

        foreach (Panel dynamicControl in persistControls)
        {
            DropDownList list = new DropDownList();
            list.ID = "list" + count;
            list.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(list_SelectedIndexChanged);
            list.AutoPostBack = true;
            list.Items.Add(new ListItem("", "0"));
            list.Items.Add(new ListItem("Title", "1"));

            dynamicControl.ID = "panel" + count;

            Button btnRemove = new Button();
            btnRemove.Click += new EventHandler(btnDelete_Click);
            btnRemove.Text = "Remove";
            btnRemove.CommandArgument = count.ToString();             

            myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(dynamicControl);
            myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(btnRemove);
            count++;
        }
    }
}

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DropDownList list = new DropDownList();
        list.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(list_SelectedIndexChanged);
        list.AutoPostBack = true;
        list.Items.Add(new ListItem("", "0"));
        list.Items.Add(new ListItem("Title", "1"));

        Panel panelContainer = new Panel();
        panelContainer.ID = "panel" + persistControls.Count;

        panelContainer.Controls.Add(list);

        Button btnRemove = new Button();
        btnRemove.Click += new EventHandler(btnDelete_Click);
        btnRemove.Text = "Remove";
        btnRemove.CommandArgument = persistControls.Count.ToString();
        myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(panelContainer); // Pushes the Panel to the page.
        persistControls.Add(panelContainer);// Adds our Panel to the Control list

        myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(btnRemove); // Pushes our Button to the page.
        Session["persistControls"] = persistControls; // put it in the session
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}

protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int deleteThisOne = int.Parse(((Button)sender).CommandArgument);
        persistControls.Remove(persistControls[deleteThisOne]);
        Session["persistControls"] = persistControls;          
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}

protected void list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

//aspx File Snippets
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Control" onclick="btnAdd_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Reset" onclick="btnClear_Click"/>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="myPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Comment: Where is the list_SelectedIndexChanged handler method?

Comment: Hi Alex, It is in the same location with the rest of the cs code ..asp.cs file. I set breakpoints on the function and was never able to get it to trigger while debugging.

Comment: **Added code to the initial post, didn't realize I could edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintaining controls like this is a real pain. You could try an alternative approach:

1. Create a (small) class that encapsulates the data you want to display in each Panel.
2. Maintain a `List` of these objects in Session.
3. Use an `<asp:Repeater>` to display the items by data-binding it to your list.
4. In the repeater's `ItemTemplate`, you can write out your `<asp:Panel>` that can contain a `<asp:DropDownList>`. Use the `ItemCommand` property of the drop-down list to bind it to a server-side event handler. Similarly you can put an `<asp:Button>` in the template and bind the `ItemCommand` property of this to another server-side event handler.
5. When you click Add, you'll postback to the server, add to your list, save it in session, re-bind the repeater.
6. When you click a Remove, you'll postback to the server, remove the item from your list, save it in session, re-bind the repeater.

This way lets ASP.Net handle all the control creation for you. However, if you really want to do all that yourself, then this [Infinities Loop blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx) is required reading.

Comment: Thank you Graham! Just for clarification... each "row" was going to populate out based on the selection of the control to the left of it. Ideally I will be passing the contents of each panel as parameters to a Stored Procedure and then binding the data from that. Is this, in your opinion, the better design approach for my problem?

Comment: ok, so when you postback on the "Add" click, you can inspect the values of the control, and populate your list object based on these. Hopefully that makes sense, I'm not quite sure I understand your page layout.

Comment: That is a nice way to say, I just re-read what I posted and it sounds strange. The idea is to that we have three buttons (Add Row Clear Row and Search). When we click Add Row, a Panel is created containing a DropDownList, from that DropDownList I would select an option that will then create another control... eventually providing the UI component for a complicated select statement.

The Clear Rows simply just clears my Control Session.

Search will be passing the information from my "row" of controls within the panel I populated through the EventHandling of each control.

Comment: I awarded this answer mainly because of the excellent resource you pointed me to, [Infinities Loop Blog Post](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work. If you create the dropdownlists in the PageLoad event, the viewstate will never get bound to it, and you will never see the option selected by the user.

You should create the controls OnInit, then when the PostBack occurs the ViewState data will get bound to the control and you will be able to access it.